# How to add images to a select option in reactjs formik

Tags: html, css, reactjs, forms, formik

I trying to add an image to select option in reactjs
I tried to put it in an img tag but it showed in the page as [object object]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I'm assuming you are using Material-UI.

Use menu item instead of a select field.

https://stackworx.github.io/formik-material-ui/docs/api/material-ui

import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem'